# Tokenize a big word into combination of words

Tags: elasticsearch, lucene

Suppose I have **Super Bowl** is the value of a document's property in the elasticsearch. How can the term query **superbowl** match **Super Bowl**?

I read about letter tokenizer and word delimiter but both don't seem to solve my problem. Basically I want to be able to convert combination of a large word into meaningful combination of words.

https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/analysis-word-delimiter-tokenfilter.html

https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/analysis-letter-tokenizer.html

Comment: What sort of field is this in?  Is it a title field?  Or something you have more control over.  My understanding is the tokenizers are designed to split up text not combine it.  However if you can index both "superbowl" and "super bowl" into that field then you can search on both

Comment: You're right it is in the title of an event. Indexing both possibilities is not happening through user input then I am okay with it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I know this is quite late but you could use [synonym filter](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/analysis-synonym-tokenfilter.html)
You could define that super bowl is the same as "s bowl", "SuperBowl" etc.

Answer (score 0):

There are ways to do this without changing what you actually index. For example, if you are using at least 5.2 (where `normalizer`s were introduced), but it can also be earlier version but 5.x makes it easier, you can define a normalizer to lowercase your text and not change it and then use a `fuzzy` query at search time to account for the space between `super` and `bowl`. My solution though is specific to this example you have given. As it is with Elasticsearch most of time, one needs to think about what kind of data goes into Elasticsearch and what it is required at search time.

In any case, if you are interested in an approach here it is:

```
DELETE test
PUT /test
{
  "settings": {
    "analysis": {
      "normalizer": {
        "my_normalizer": {
          "type": "custom",
          "char_filter": [],
          "filter": ["lowercase", "asciifolding"]
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "mappings": {
    "test": {
      "properties": {
        "title": {
          "type": "text",
          "fields": {
            "keyword": {
              "type": "keyword",
              "normalizer": "my_normalizer"
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
POST test/test/1
{"title":"Super Bowl"}

GET /test/_search
{
  "query": {
    "fuzzy": {
      "title.keyword": "superbowl"
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Normalisers are experimental feature and may be removed or changed later. Why don't massage your data at index time in your code ? If you know what you are going to search for, this should be simple.

Comment: @krrish An experimental feature in Elasticsearch is not there to scare people off, but more to protect possible feature changes in future. And a normalizer has anyway a "normal" way to do it ;-): define the field as `text` and use a customer analyzer with `keyword` and `lowercase` filter. No biggie.